# Combining noSQL and ORM in an MVC framework for a real-case application

Tags: django, model-view-controller, orm, nosql, playframework

I've been trying for some time to put some 'cool' things I've been reading about noSQL (couchDB, mongoDB, Redis...) in the past years into practical use.

I'm quite used to writing apps with Django, and started using Play! when Java is the only acceptable deployment option (and enjoying it too). Both have modules to work, for instance, with [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), and django also has [nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel). But i never felt a need for noSQL.

Until I finally found what I thought was a good use case for document-oriented storage, such as MongoDB.

### Use Case

Let's say we have to manage ordering and follow up (whatever) of some complex items. The items might have a lot of different properties, eg. oversimplifying we could have:

- a Fridge that can have

  - one or two doors,
  - be of class A,B or C,
  - a surface color
  - standalone or built-in
- an Oven that can have:

  - gas or electricity or both
  - self cleaning or not
  - standalone or built-in

### SQL/ORM solution

As you can see, each object can have several properties that can be constrained by type.

In my usual RDBMS through an ORM I would go with defining a "product" model, then inherit two models, a Fridge and an Oven.
If a Fridge gets one more property some time after, I modify the model - and as such, the schema-, run a migration, and add a column.

### noSQL solutions

noSQL solutions I can think of are:

- using RDF (with something like [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) or building my own simplified triples storage)
- using a document-oriented db such as MongoDB

### The Problem

But **I fail at understanding how different (easier) development would *pragmatically* be** switching to a noSQL solution still using the framework ORM with the right adapter (especially with DODB).

Let's say I'm using Django with MongoDB through mongodb-engine.

I'm still using the same ORM, so I still describe those objects as models, listing all properties. 
The ORM is thus doing exactly the same job!
The cost of producing a migration if the model changes is very limited with an ORM (in particular with something like South), nothing requiring to learn a new technology by itself.

There might be /other/ advantages to a DODB, and some specific to MongoDB (scalability, data-processing, maybe performance) but... what about the exact use case and problem I'm describing?

I am most likely missing a point, so here come the real question(s):

For this specific use case:

- is this example a good or bad one for DODB (do you have a good one)?
- would it make sense to combine an ORM for basic stuff (Users, Orders) and usage of noSQL **without** ORM for complex objects, is there a compelling reason to switch to noSQL completely, or should I stay with the stock ORM/SQL?

I understand answering these questions could be partially subjective, so you can assume perfect knowledge of both noSQL and SQL theory, and stock ORM; existence of good bridges from stock ORMs to noSQL DB. Let's assume we are talking about this use case with MongoDB as noSQL alternative.

But there is a more general question - which is the core question of this SO post:

- **Isn't a good ORM (such as JPA, ActiveRecord, or Django's one) making noSQL and in particular document-oriented databases of little use?**
- ...and is it worth using noSQL with a 'classic' ORM?

("little use" from a programming and maintenance standpoint, performance and similar criteria are a different matter and would require a precise product-to-product comparison)

**[edit]**

What I am also trying to understand is if it wouldn't be better to drop using an ORM when switching to noSQL. It would be nice to have more "dynamic" models, eg. I could have a table describing what the Fridge and Oven *models* are (fields), and the Fridge and Oven models in the code would be able to construct their views dynamically (forms for editing and listings for displaying).

### Related questions:

**[edit]**: these are here to show my research, but also to clarify that what I am asking is not generic about noSQL vs. SQL

- [Is an ORM redundant with a NoSQL API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694044/is-an-orm-redundant-with-a-nosql-api) : similar! but I am trying to see why most frameworks (see above) are providing noSQL access through their ORMs. Is that a good idea or not?
- [why the use of an ORM with NoSql (like MongoDB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051614/why-the-use-of-an-orm-with-nosql-like-mongodb) : more specific than the previous one, but still is the other way around. I'm arguing that **ORMs make noSQL unuseful**, rather than the other way around!
- [When to replace RDBMS/ORM with NoSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522069/when-to-replace-rdbms-orm-with-nosql)
- [When to use MongoDB or other document oriented database systems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476295/when-to-use-mongodb-or-other-document-oriented-database-systems)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54373/when-would-someone-use-mongodb-or-similar-over-traditional-rdms

**EDIT**
And links:

- [Siena](http://www.sienaproject.com/index.html): a persistence API for Java inspired by the Google App Engine Python Datastore trying to draw a bridge between SQL and NoSQL worlds.
- [minimongo](https://github.com/slacy/minimongo):  lightweight, schemaless, Pythonic Object-Oriented interface to MongoDB

Comment: http://slacy.com/blog/2011/01/announcing-availability-of-minimongo-a-micro-orm-for-mongodb-in-python/ this seems to go in the direction I'm thinking about. Don't use "classic" orms with nosql = use custom orms or don't use nosql :)

Comment: flagged this to be moved to Programmers

Comment: I found an interesting project: [Siena](http://www.sienaproject.com/index.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I get for trolling stackoverflow. Once in a great while an outstanding question gets asked and I am compelled to offer my 2 cents (at the risk of my own project timelines).

I just finished up a project where I had to de-couple an ORM from the model so I could implement a NoSQL solution, and found it not that difficult, although it was rough at times trying to figure out the best approach. So without getting too specific about my implementation, I will touch on what I had to do to make it work, as it may offer some enlightenment when you travel down the same path.

My setup:

- Framework - Symfony 1.4
- ORM - Doctrine 1.4
- NoSQL - My own proprietary solution

Goal:

- Store image paths within xml files vs the database
- Store html description paths within xml files vs the database

I didn't want to store images as blobs within the persistent store (database), and I didn't want to store image paths in the database, as I didn't want to pay the overhead of creating a database connection and querying for the path. So I decided to store the path information within a NoSQL persistent store (filesystem).

And ditto for html descriptions, I didn't want to create a text column on my table and store what could potentially be hundreds of lines of html within the database, and the same reasons as above.

All my NoSQL files relate to an object (refrigerator for example). These files contain paths to their related assets (html description and images), in what I call pointers, which point to the assets on the filesystem. I opted to use XML format for storing the data so it looks something like this:

```
// Path to pointer file
/home/files/app/needle/myApp/refrigerator/1/1.xml

// Example pointer
<pointer>/home/files/app/file/myApp/refrigerator/1.png</pointer>
```

Now, within the framework I had to override the save() methods so I could save the aforementioned assets using the NoSQL API. It was pretty easy, I just checked the parent calls and maintained the values coming into the methods, so they wouldn't break any chain logic (methods calling other methods with the same arguments), that I wasn't aware of. I also made my custom NoSQL API calls throw exceptions as the main save() call was wrapped in a try/catch block. The only thing you have to be careful of here, is determining whether your NoSQL assets are worth stopping the entire transaction. In my example, I had to figure out if uploading an image would break saving the rest of the form fields in the database (I opted to break the transaction).

I also had to alter the load() methods to retrieve the assets using the NoSQL API vs the standard model logic. As with the save methods, this wasn't too hard to do either. I just had to see what the parent classes were doing and not muck with any argument values.

When all was said and done, I was able to store images and html descriptions on the filesystem, with an xml file made up of pointers pointing to their location. So now I don't incur a database call every time I need an asset.

Some considerations (these may be included in other NoSQL solutions, I had to write my own):

- You will not be able to query for refrigerators that have images from your persistent store. You will have to write some logic in your application to pull in the assets from the NoSQL store.
- Backups: As you backup your persistent store data, you also need to backup your NoSQL data.
- Orphans: Now that your schema is unaware of any assets you may have, deleting a row from your persistent store will orphan an asset on the filesystem. So be sure your application has the logic to clean the NoSQL store when a row has been deleted.

I think I hit all the major hurdles I faced when implementing a NoSQL solution with an ORM, if you have any other questions feel free to hit me up.

-- Edit --

Responses to comments:

1. As I mentioned I didn't want to create a database connection and query just to get a path to an asset. I feel it's better to use a NoSQL solution for this type of information as there is really no reason run queries against this type of information (images or html descriptions).
2. Developing my own NoSQL solution was more of an ego challenge. At work there was a project to implement a custom NoSQL solution (had bad experiences with MogileFS), and to be frank, was poorly designed and poorly implemented. But rather than just point out the bad, I challenged myself to offer up a better solution, but for a side project. And because of the challenge aspect, I didn't research any already available NoSQL solutions, but in hindsight I probably should have.

I still think you can implement MongoDB or any NoSQL solution by overriding crud functions with the Model layer of your ORM, relatively easy. In fact, not only did I implement my NoSQL solution, I also added the ability to index data into SOLR (for full-text searching) during crud functions as well, so anything is possible.

Comment: Thanks @Digital-Precision for sharing! I briefly went through it and, though I have to take more time for the details, I must say that this is still a quite "simple" noSQL (filesystem). For these situations I also usually (in Django) extend the Model in a similar way as yours, and it sounds like it definitely makes sense to extend/modify the orm in a specific way. The choice becomes more complicated when complex noSQL is involved, such as document-oriented storage. The advantage of an ORM there is to introduce some abstraction that you are not required in your use case (am i clear?!)

Comment: Took the time to go through it again, slowly. Indeed even for a "simpler" use case you still got to face most of the out-of-orm issues I can think of! I now have two main questions that I'll make in separate comments....

Comment: Q1) why didn't you simply add the resource-path information into the database, then retrieve it along with the main model with a [DQL](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/zh/working-with-models#dealing-with-relations:retrieving-related-records)? This would have avoided making multiple queries while allowing you to maintain the ORM approach (I do not know how doctrine helps with file-storage though). For datablobs in database or in filesystem, it's a difficult call - I'm not sure file system is really better than a good DB.. but you loose on the coding.

Comment: Q2) in your specific use case this probably was less useful, but did you think about existing noSQL solutions with a real DB and their own (or an integrated) ORM? For my needs a file storage definitely wouldn't  be enough, and a document-oriented noSQL sounds good. If I take your route I would avoid any ORM and just hack the existing one for save, delete, and data retrieval. This would definitely be a one shot code. Is this better than any existing noSql /or/ Sql ORM? I know this one part of the question is actually too broad :)

Comment: @Stefano: What did you end up going with?

Comment: @Mike: My specific implementation was in Play!; I finally decided I wanted to keep the ORM to re-use the autogenerated admin interfaces (CRUD). And since there really was no real advantage in using the ORM with noSQL for my use-case (and, I feel, in most cases!) I made my own database abstraction, similar to a Triple RDF system but more  custom-made to my use-case needs. I still feel that mongoDB would have been a better fit, but I could not be bothered with an SQL-like ORM, let alone no ORM/CRUD at all!

Comment: @Stefano: Never saw your response until now. Glad to hear you resolved your issue. Just keep in mind that NoSQL is a viable alternative to storing non-relational data.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am also trying to understand is if it wouldn't be better to
>   drop using an ORM when switching to noSQL

It's not really beneficial to drop the ORM entirely. But you may have to rewrite it quite a bit. There are lots of little things like transactions, evented sequential writes, error handling, and data integrity checks that an ORM could handle for you in a noSQL fashion.

ORMs aren't meant to handle every possible feature, even in SQL. They just do "most" of the heavy lifting. That's why the django ORM provides a direct access to SQL class when you need it.

Comment: Thanks, this goes towards my still unprecise impression. Now, what I more pragmatically am trying to understand is if for Play! and Django (RoR...) it makes sense to keep the existing ORM, or if a (totally) new one should be designed from scratch, more suitable to the schemaless nature of noSQL (key-value or d-o). I am under the impression, for instance, that the Play! Morphia or django-mongodb engine approach is limited because there's little benefit of switching to MongoDB if the ORM programming is (almost) exactly the same. The biggest advantage seems limited to avoiding foreign keys!

Answer (score 0):

It's quite an open question, there is no "correct" answer. The decision between NoSQL and SQL (ORM) depends on too many factors. Some questions I would ask:

- How familar are you with both technologies?
- In your scenario, what's the impact of trade - offs? Relational model provides some guarantees NoSQL doesn't, and the other way around
- How often may your model change? Evolution of the application usually requires model changes, but how much of it do you expect?

As I told you, it's open ended. My personal suggestion would be to start modelling with the technology you know. You can always integrate new components later, if you really need it.

Of course if the interest is purely "academical" to use NoSQL, don't mind about the optimal scenarios, use it, you'll see what's good and bad about it.

**EDIT on comment (answer doesn't fit in comment's area):**

@Stefano I'm afraid I don't see your point, as usage fo NoSQL in frameworks (or usage of an ORM) depends on your needs.

It's not a problem of "is good to use this tool in this framework", as support is (often) excellent. The issue should be "Do I need to use this tool, why and what benefits does it give me?".

If the answer is "yes, I need this because A,B and/or C" then just go ahead and use it.

If the answer is "no, because A or B" or "it doesn't make a difference", then either don't use it or choose the option you are most familiar with from the ones available to you.

That is, the fact that one framework supports something doesn't mean it's worse or better or should or shouldn't be used. That's why I put my questions. In the end, it IS a question about NoSQL vs SQL, as the tools you use to integrate it (ORM, SQL, whatever) are just a channel to access the data, and that's less relevant than the storage system you pick for your problem (as the tool will be limited by the storage system by definition)

Comment: Thanks Pere, I agree it /can/ be an open question and indeed I have some "academical" interest; but what I'm trying to nail down, while related to your (2nd and 3rd) questions, is wrt using noSQL with an ORM, such as ActiveRecord for Rails, or Django's one, or JPA for Java. With such ORMs I have the feeling most of the advantages of noSQL from a programming point disappear, including migrations (there might be other criteria such as performance). My question is thus not so much about SQL vs. noSQL, rather usage of noSQL in typical frameworks such as Django, Play!, Rails, etc.

Comment: 1) only theoretically familiar with noSQL 2) That's part of what I want to understand. what are those "guarantees"? 3) From time to time. Often at the beginning, every month or so afterwards

Comment: Pete, I answered your questions (though the 2nd one is actually part of my question!), but I still can't agree that mine is a question about noSQL vs SQL. Since ORMs in most modern frameworks can be used *with* noSQL and SQL, my question stands as whether it makes sense to use such an ORM with noSQL.

Comment: Finally I am realizing that your "ORM vs. noSQL" answer is quite true, but that's because there are no ORMs I am aware of that are good enought to bring the noSQL advantages into a framework!! See my comments to DigitalPrecision if you are interested, and I might be adding a full answer later on (though I will not accept it as it will be only a very specific application, not a good overall solution)!