# Mapping C# objects to database schema

Tags: c#, database, orm

I'm developing a *client-server desktop application system* in *C#*.
The client is merely a thin client that displays whatever the server tells it to.
The server communicates directly with a local database which is used for storing metadata for a variety of systems. Each system will have its own table, whose structure is unique for that system.

I'm trying to understand how I can tell the desktop application about the structure of the database without "hard-coding" anything, if that makes sense. I believe I need to look into [Object-relational mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) but I'm not quite sure where to start, as I've never taken on a project of this complexity before. The idea would be that my server configuration somehow defines this mapping, and it would possibly be extensible so I can add more mappings for more systems in the future, or possible change the mapping.

*How I see this system working is like this:*

> A user on the client uploads a file containing the metadata to the
>   server. The server would determine for which system type this file is
>   for, then parse the file to extract the metadata, and enter it into
>   the database. The way I had initially envisioned this happening is
>   that I would have a generic abstract class/interface which would need
>   to be derived for each system type. The derived class would then
>   implement a parsing function specific to that system type so it can
>   extract the metadata from the file. But the problem here is that I
>   have no way of entering the extracted data into the database, since
>   the server doesn't know the underlying structure of the derived class.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've found [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/), which kind of sounds like what I might need, but I'm not 100% sure. *Part of the problem is, as I stated earlier, I don't have a full understanding of some of these concepts.* Can anyone recommend some online resources that might help me to understand *Object Relational Mapper(ORM)* in general, and specifically how it pertains to *.Net Framework*?

Comment: "The client is merely a thin client that displays whatever the server tells it to."-Wat "I'm trying to understand how I can tell the desktop application about the structure of the database without "hard-coding" anything" wat, structure means you've hard coded something. "A user on the client uploads a file containing the metadata to the server. The server would determine for which system type this file is for, then parse the file to extract the metadata, and enter it into the database." that's called a controller(and data exchange format).

Comment: if you don't want structure or hardcoded anything, just use a NoSQL database. If you want structure and ORM use Entity Framework

Comment: since the server doesn't know the underlying structure of the derived class. -- sounds like you don't even need ORM. Do you actually have to have relationships in your data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ultimate question here isn't which *Object Relational Mapper (ORM)* to use, but ultimately what such a mapper does.  This particular layer is often interlaced into a *Data Access Layer (DAL)*.

You see the function here is essentially a technique to *convert* between incompatible types.  Essentially it creates a *Virtual Object Database* that can be utilized.  The importance of this layer is to link your *Domain Logic / Business Layer* to your *Data Access Layer or Object Relational Mapper*.  This essentially helps decouple logic that doesn't require access to your data structure- Which makes the decoupling between your *User Interface, Domain Logic, and Data Access Layer* more coherent.

The *Interface* has no knowledge of how your *Data Layer* is speaking to your data structure.  Currently I've been mixing the *Data Access Layer* and *Object Relational Mapper* due to the similarities but they are quite different.

*How is a Data Access Layer different from an Object Relational Mapper*

Compared to traditional techniques of exchange between an *object-oriented language* and a *relational database*, an *Object Relational Mapper* often reduces the amount of code that needs to be written.  This benefit is apparent- but includes a massive pitfall.  They tend to overly abstract what is occuring, which obscures what *actually* is happening.

Another thing to consider, if you overly rely on the *ORM* it may produce a poorly designed database.

[image: Object Relational Mapper Theory]

As you can see from the diagram, that is the theory behind an *Object Relational Mapper*.  Where as a *Data Access Layer* often found within an *N-Tier Architecture* or *Service Oriented Architecture*.

[image: Data Access Layer]

*The major difference between the two is:*

> Object-Relational Mapping tools provide data layers in this fashion,
>   following the active record model. The ORM/active-record model is
>   popular with web frameworks.
>
> Where the *Data Access Layer* is layer which simplifies access to data
>   stored in a persistent storage of some kind. Applications using a data
>   access layer can be either database server dependent or independent.
>   If the data access layer supports multiple database types, the
>   application becomes able to use whatever databases the DAL can talk
>   to. In either circumstance, having a data access layer provides a
>   centralized location for all calls into the database, and thus makes
>   it easier to port the application to other database systems (assuming
>   that 100% of the database interaction is done in the DAL for a given
>   application).

As you can now see the similarities and differences, but what about the data structure?  Am I forced within a database?  The short answer is *no*.  You have some of these choices:

- *Relational Data*: You would use a more traditional *Database* approach.
- *NoSQL:* Object Relational Mappers* have arose that follow the *NoSQL* approach.

This will provide greater flexibility based upon the requirements of your project. A wonderful question on *Stack Overflow* actually has a real-world with a *NoSQL* approach. [(here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349020/combining-nosql-and-orm-in-an-mvc-framework-for-a-real-case-application)

Four highly distinct benefits are:

- *Productivity*: The data access code is usually a significant portion
  of a typical application, and the time needed to write that code can
  be a significant portion of the overall development schedule. When
  using an ORM tool, the amount of code is unlikely to be reduced—in
  fact, it might even go up—but the ORM tool generates 100% of the data
  access code automatically based on the data model you define, in mere
  moments.
- *Application design:* A good ORM tool designed by very experienced
  software architects will implement effective design patterns that
  almost force you to use good programming practices in an application.
  This can help support a clean separation of concerns and independent
  development that allows parallel, simultaneous development of
  application layers.
- *Code Reuse:* If you create a class library to generate a separate DLL
  for the ORM-generated data access code, you can easily reuse the data
  objects in a variety of applications. This way, each of the
  applications that use the class library need have no data access code
  at all.
- *Application Maintainability:* All of the code generated by the ORM is
  presumably well-tested, so you usually don’t need to worry about
  testing it extensively. Obviously you need to make sure that the code
  does what you need, but a widely used ORM is likely to have code
  banged on by many developers at all skill levels. Over the long term,
  you can refactor the database schema or the model definition without
  affecting how the application uses the data objects.

*Obviously take those with a grain of salt, because an application is tested doesn't mean it can't be test further or made better.*

You can find a large list of *Object Relational Mappers:*

- [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)
- [NHibernate](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://nhforge.org/&ei=TUnTUcyEFqeYigLlioCICw&usg=AFQjCNHrjOQksx0_3hIE5JCPxBspGAw7aw&sig2=ERRy4eThQOlyUCNigxsvyA&bvm=bv.48705608,d.cGE)
- [Open Access](http://www.telerik.com/products/orm.aspx)

Those are just a few of the large quantity available, a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software) with a list. Some are great, some are not.  **The ultimate goal will be to find which one adheres closely to your desired application goal-**

Hopefully that really helps you out.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, but I'm still very confused. I think I lack a lot of the fundamental understanding that is required for this type of... abstract thinking, if you will.

Can you recommend some resources where I can learn more about this?

Comment: @ACS Yeah, you'll want to look into N-Tier, Entity Framework, Data Access Layer.  Microsoft has a great article if you google C# Data Access Layer.

Comment: Forget all the algo blah blah and consider this: You have a class in C# called "User" (that's your table), the "User" class has a property called "Pseudo" (that's your column), now most of these ORM things just allow you to say: Hey! Take this DB Connection string of my database and map it to my class "User" ..tada ORM. In the end it simply allows you to connect to a database and use the tables/columns as simple C# objects without having to write any SQL. Or it allows you to simply create your C# model, and then tell it to create the database for you, and manage things with little to no SQL.

Comment: You can consider "Object Relational Mapping (ORM)" to be just another fancy name for "Database Abstraction Layer (DAL)"

Comment: @Robert You are 100% correct, you just managed to simplify the meaning compared to my answer.  Though it still does have drawbacks; but that is a great addition and nice comment.

Answer (score 3):

Check out OrmLite
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite

Syntax is very nice, actually a lot of things from service stack are nice.

They also list a bunch of alternatives here
http://www.servicestack.net/benchmarks/